# How to solve the StopIteration issue while the XML tag does not have a value using Python script

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling, web.xml, stopiteration

I am using ixml to parse the XML doxument.

```
from lxml import etree
root=etree.XML(full xml tag file content)
 if (next(root.iterfind(".//one_inner_tag")).text is None):
      Print "NONE VALUE"
 else:
      Print root.iterfind(".//one_inner_tag")).text
```

While executing this code, I have faced an error like

```
if (next(root.iterfind(".//one_inner_tag")).text is None):
StopIteration
```

Because of the file content does not have that specific tag.
If the Tag does not have a value means I need to print the NONE VALUE. But it prints the error.

Comment: You could check the length of the iterable returned from iterfind, instead of calling next and comapring to None

Comment: This code is wasteful - you're doing the `iterfind` twice: once to determine if the element exists, and then another time to actually extract the text.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: It's actually broken, not just wasteful. No iteration was done in the second use, so it's trying to get `.text` on the generator itself, which wouldn't work. In addition, it's got the wrong `print` capitalization (and if it's Py3 or Py2 with the `__future__` `print_function` import, it needs parens around the arguments to `print` to boot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Python generator to return None rather than StopIteration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102050/how-can-i-get-a-python-generator-to-return-none-rather-than-stopiteration)

Answer (score 2):

`next` can take a second argument that is returned on exhaustion of the iterator, so try:

```
elem = next(root.iterfind(".//one_inner_tag"), None)  # Returns None on empty iterator
if elem is None or elem.text is None:
    print "NONE VALUE"
else:
    print elem.text
```